# Showing data from an array of objects on React component : TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, typeerror

I have now been trying to solve this problem for some days, and it seems like the solution should be just in front of me. But nothing seems to work for me. This is my first React app, so may do somethings completly off... :D

I have this data

```
const teamNames = ['Sort', 'Gul', 'Blå', 'Rød', 'Orange',  'Grøn']
let [finalTeamData, setFinalTeamData] = useState()
```

In my function I do like this, first reset the data and then building it.

```js
  function makeTeams () {
    const playersParticipating = []
    let howManyTeams = 0
    const teams = []
    setFinalTeamData(finalTeamData = [])

    // Get the players who is participating
    for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
      if (players[i].participating) {
        playersParticipating.push(players[i].name)
      }
    }
    
    // Find the number of players pr team.
    howManyTeams = playersParticipating.length / parseInt(teamsize)    
    
    // Divide the players out on each team randomly
    // Taking 1 team at a time
    for (let i = 0; i < howManyTeams; i++) {      
      teams[i] = []
      for (let y = 0; y < teamsize; y++) {
        let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * playersParticipating.length)
        teams[i].push(playersParticipating[number])
        playersParticipating.splice(number, 1)   
      }
    }
    console.log(teams)
    setShowteams(true)
    for (let i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
      setFinalTeamData(finalTeamData[i] =
        {
          id: i,
          teamname: teamNames[i],
          players: teams[i]
        }
      )

    }
    console.log(finalTeamData)
  }
```

Passing it into my component here

```
<ShowTeams data={finalTeamData} />
```

Lastly here is my component.

```js
const ShowTeams = ({ data }) => {

        return (
            <>
                {data.map((data) => { return <h1>{data.teamname}</h1>;})}
            </>
    )
}

export default ShowTeams
```

But no matter how I try to do it, I keep getting this error: TypeError: data.map is not a function

How do I problaly go through my data and display every object on the component?

As far as I can see it should be an array, and it looks correct in the browser console. Hope someone have the time to have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the default value of `finalTeamData` is `undefined`. When you use `useState`, it's important to set a default value especially if you're accessing it immediately without checking it.

Reason:

In the initial render of your component, `finalTeamData` will be `undefined` even if you run `makeTeam` before the render. It takes another cycle before the render gets the updated value.

Solution:

```
const [finalTeamData, setFinalTeamData] = useState([]);
```

Also, I suggest creating a function that returns the calculated `finalTeamData` and setting that value using `setFinalTeamData`.

```
const makeTeam = () => {
  ...calculate
  return teamData
}
const [finalTeamData, setFinalTeamData] = useState(makeTeam());
```

This way your default value will be the calculated teams. You might also want to take into account when you want to update the `finalTeamData`.

Depending on how often it is or if ever the value changes, you can take a look at `useEffect` to update it.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

## UPDATE

After reviewing the code again, this snippet concerned me:

```
setFinalTeamData(finalTeamData[i] =
  {
    id: I,
    teamname: teamNames[i],
    players: teams[i]
  }
);
```

You don't want to directly modify the state value and you'd want to use the setter function. Your default value is an array so I would modify this to:

```
const teamData = [];

for (let i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
  teamData.push({
    id: i,
    teamname: teamNames[i],
    players: teams[i]
  });
}

setFinalTeamData(teamData);
```

You also don't need this line:

```
setFinalTeamData(finalTeamData = [])
```

https://dev.to/koralarts/react-usestate-5h75

Comment: I have tried with the line so the state is set at the start, it gets the same error message.

The finalTeamData looks like this in the console.

[{…}]
0: {id: 0, teamname: "Sort", players: Array(3)}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: Ok let me update my answer. I see another issue.

Comment: That made the trick, much appreciated for your time and answers, very helpfull.